# What does "the order product has been reduced" mean?

Tags: order, orderitem

We have been using Orders and Order Products for about a year in a really fundamental way, just to feed into a custom built Invoice object. It's recurring monthly Invoicing, so the values on the Orders can change from month to month. I am now suddenly getting errors when attempting to edit some Order Products that **"You can't update Quantity because the order product has been reduced."** I understand from Salesforce Documentation that Order Products are not editable after they have been reduced, I just can't find any explanation of what "reduced" means.

We have the 'Reduction Orders" option ticked in Setup, but we've never created any that I know of. I don't actually really understand what they are, as we sell services and don't do returns. I thought maybe just deactivating an order, reducing a quantity, and reactivating the Order might trigger this behavior, but I haven't been able to reproduce it on other orders in that way. I haven't yet found the commonality in the Orders of ours that are displaying this behavior.

What does it mean that we've "reduced" the Order Product? How can I replicate it/avoid accidentally doing it in the future? And is there a way around this limitation now that some of our Orders are not editable, or do we have to scrap them and create new ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Reduction Orders](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.orderreduction_overview.htm&type=5) covers what it is referring to:

> Use reduction orders to track requests to reduce, return, deactivate, or disable a customer’s products or services.

> A reduction order is an agreement between a company and a customer to process product returns, deprovision services, or reduce services that have been provisioned. For example, if a customer has purchased 30 items through an order and then requests to cancel that order, you can create a reduction order to track the request.

[OrderItem](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_orderitem.htm) has a lookup to itself called `OriginalOrderItemId`

> Required if isReductionOrder on the parent order is true.
>
> ID of the original **order product being reduced**.

The current `OrderItem` you're editing is most likely being referenced in this lookup in one of your other `OrderItems` in the org. As it's referenced, it's assuming it's a reduction order item. This error will be thrown when updating certain fields on a reduction order item.

- Quantity
- UnitPrice
- ListPrice
- PriceBookEntry
- ProvisioningRequestDate
- ServiceDate
- EndDate

In your error message, it says you're updating `Quantity`.

---

`OriginalOrderItemId` is **not updateable** so you will have to *delete* the OrderItem (and presumably, re-create afterwards) that is referencing the one you're trying to update to freely edit Quantity.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. It was spot on! We have a custom field called 'Previous Order Item' but accidentally populated 'OriginalOrderItemId' along with it. That's causing Salesforce to think the Order Product is related to a reduction Order.

And you're right, it is very much "not updateable." I even emailed support to see if they could work magic on the backend but they just pointed me to the API docs and said, "Sorry, nothing we can do either." So we'll be deleting and recreating some items.

Comment: If you don't leverage reduction orders, you could just turn off `Reduction Options` and that validation won't run. But, unfortunately, deleting will be the only option otherwise.

Comment: Are you talking about `Setup` | `Order Settings` | `Enable Reduction Orders`? We don't use reduction orders, so I found and unchecked that option right away when we had this problem. But it still throws the error. Are you talking about a different setting?

Comment: Apologies - I thought that setting in setup was related to the underlying permission used in the check. However, I see now it's tied to the license so you don't have any option there. You are forced to delete. I'll update my answer